# Change Gridview item visibility

Tags: android, gridview, custom-adapter

I have a Gridview and Custom adapter.

in my adapter, i have a static ViewHolder instance.

```
static class ViewHolder
{ 
  TextView _model,tPrice,pPrice;
  ImageView picture;
}
```

This is my ViewHolder. When the user clicked a button in the fragment, I just want to make tPrice visibility GONE.
When i create a istance of the adapter i send an integer parameter for tPrice VISIBLITY. But its data still on the static data. I wanna change the this area. i need an instance of my current view. i will cast it to my ViewHolder. After do this i set the visiblity. But How can I do it?

Here are the getView and my constructer

```
private int TFV = View.GONE;
private int PFV=  View.GONE;

public ProductGridViewAdapter(Context p_context, int p_resourceId,ArrayList<Product> p_ProductList,int TFVisib,int PFVisib){
    super(p_context,p_resourceId,p_ProductList);
    originalItems = p_ProductList;
     TFV = TFVisib;
     PFV = PFVisib;
    _ctx = p_context;
    //....
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View row = convertView;
    if(row==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();      
        row = li.inflate(_resourceId, null);
        holder._model = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.o_model);    
        holder.pPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_pf);  
        holder.tPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_tf);  
        holder.picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.product_lv_image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Product f =null;

    if(originalItems!=null)
         f = originalItems.get(position);
    if (f != null) {
         holder._model.setText(f.GetCODE());
         holder.pPrice.setText(f.GetPRICE());
         holder.pPrice.setVisibility(PFV);
         holder.tPrice.setVisibility(TFV);
         holder.tPrice.setText(f.GetCURRENCY());
         File imgFile = new  File(uhandler.GetProductsFolderPath()+"/BIG"+f.GetCODE()+".jpg");
         if(imgFile.exists()){
             Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
             holder.picture.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
         }
    }
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem. I had set the adapter again. This way may be a bad way but its work :)

Answer (score 0):

In your custom adapter class, look at the `getView()` method, in which you can set GONE or VISIBLE or INVISIBLE value to the tPrice TextView or any Views if you want.

Comment: tPrice VISIBILITY is VISIBLE okey. When i clicked the button, i send a data to adapter, this data trigger the visiblity but i still visible

Comment: when click event triggered the instance of the adapters parameter will changed on the fragment